# MariaDB install failling on Debian 10 based VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, mariadb, debian-buster

Trying to simply install MariaDB server on Azure Debian 10 VM host
However it fails during the process

I had tried few different ways but it seems to get stuck somewhere in the half way

The last i tried was using this link https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mariadb-on-debian-10-buster/

It goes fine up to 86% then I get a error message saying

[image]

Is this some known bug ? any ideas how where to start fault finding ?

thanks

AB

Comment: Where is the rest of it?

Comment: there is no rest, process get stuck on that
so I had to abort installation to get CLI back